# How boost a DVB-C signal

Tags: amplifier, signal, tv, coax, hd

I receive a DVB-C signal from my broadcast TV provider, and I use coaxial cables and some splitters to connect my three televisions to the coaxial wall-socket.

Unfortunately I have problems to receive all TV channels: I can watch most of them with good/perfect quality, but some channels (especially HD channels, but also some SD channels) are not received at all, or with very bad quality.

I've already checked to connect only one TV directly to the wall-socket with a short cable, and in this way all channels are perfect, included HD. Therefore, as it was easy to presume, the problem is due to the cables and/or splitters, and not to my TV provider.

I bought new cables, splitters and also a signal booster/amplifier, but the problem remain.

So my question are:

- **is it better to use a single 10 meters long cable (as I assume) or two 5 meters cables 'in series'?**
- **where it is advisable to install the booster? Directly connected to the wall-socket (to not  amplify unnecessarily noise due to cables/splitters)? Or before/after the splitters?**

Answer (score 1):

You have an adequate signal for one TV and then you split that into three - the power of the signal, in simple terms is now one-third what it was when one TV was used. I'd advise putting the booster between "antenna" and the point where the splitter is but it may still not work due to reflections.

You have started with a signal that has (say) 50 ohms impedance and fed it down some 50 ohm coax to a splitter - have you made any attempt to match the three outgoing cables to the incoming cable? Does the splitter do that for you? If you don't know you need to find out because teeing off a piece of coax to make a spur is going to cause reflections and seriously deteriorate you signal more than the 3:1 caused by power-sharing.